# Gulpfile.js optimization and image caching

Tags: javascript, beginner, node.js, gulp.js

I'm trying to write [gulpfile.js](https://github.com/Skoks/performer/blob/master/gulpfile.js), which will follow modern best practices for optimization. This project includes jekyll, SASS and some image optimization tasks. I'm pretty new to JavaScript and Gulp, so I'd love to get some feedback on this code.

You can also check the [Github repo](https://github.com/Skoks/performer).

```
'use strict';

var gulp            = require('gulp'),
    plumber         = require('gulp-plumber'),
    gutil           = require('gulp-util'),
    notify          = require('gulp-notify'),
    size            = require('gulp-size'),
    rename          = require('gulp-rename'),
    sass            = require('gulp-sass'),
    autoprefixer    = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    cmq             = require('gulp-combine-media-queries'),
    minifyCSS       = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    jshint          = require('gulp-jshint'),
    concat          = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify          = require('gulp-uglify'),
    psi             = require('psi'),
    ngrok           = require('ngrok'),
    cp              = require('child_process'),
    browserSync     = require('browser-sync'),
    imageMin        = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    cwebp           = require('gulp-cwebp'),
    imageResize     = require('gulp-image-resize'),
    cache           = require('gulp-cache'),
    cached          = require('gulp-cached'),
    changed         = require('gulp-changed'),
    newer           = require('gulp-newer'),
    parallel        = require('concurrent-transform'),
    os              = require('os-utils'),
    minifyHTML      = require('gulp-minify-html'),
    clean           = require('gulp-clean'),
    url             = 'http://1ec934f4.ngrok.com/',
    reload          = browserSync.reload;

var onError         = function(err) {
    gutil.beep();
    gutil.log(gutil.colors.green(err + '\n'));
};

var messages = {
    jekyllBuild: '<span style="color: grey">Running:</span> $ jekyll build'
};

/*==========  Paths  ==========*/

var paths = {
    styles: {
        src:            'assets/sass/main.scss',
        dest:           'build/css',
        destProd:       'html/build/css',
        watch:          'assets/sass/**/*.scss',
        style:          'build/css/main.css',
        styleProd:      'html/build/css/main.css',
        styleMin:       'build/css/main.min.css',
        styleMinProd:   'html/build/css/main.min.css'
    },
    scripts: {
        src:            'assets/js/**/*.js',
        dest:           'build/js',
        destProd:       'html/build/js',
        destVen:        'assets/js/vendor',
        script:         'build/js/main.js',
        scriptProd:     'html/build/js/main.js',
        scriptMin:      'build/js/main.min.js',
        scriptMinProd:  'html/build/js/main.min.js',
        bundleMain:     'build/js/main.bundle.js',
        bundleMainMin:  'build/js/main.bundle.min.js',
        watch:          ['assets/js/**/*.js', '!/assets/js/vendor/**/*.js']
    },
    jshint: {
        src: [
                        'assets/js/**/*.js',
                        '!assets/js/vendor/**/*.js'
        ]
    },
    bundles: {
        main: [
                        'assets/js/main.js',
                        'assets/js/vendor/**/*.js',
                        '!assets/js/vendor/bootstrap-sprockets.js',
                        '!assets/js/vendor/bootstrap.js',
        ]
    },
    images: {
        src:            'assets/img/**/*.{jpg, png, svg, gif, webp}',
        dest:           'build/img',
        destOpt:        'build/img/opt',
        destProd:       'html/build/img',
        watch:          'assets/img/**/*.{jpg, png, svg, gif, webp}',
        watchOpt:       'build/img/opt/*.{jpg, png, svg, gif, webp}',
        watchDest:      'build/img/*.{jpg, png, svg, gif, webp}',
        watchProd:      'html/build/img/**/*.{jpg, png, svg, gif, webp}'
    },
    html: {
        dest:           'html',
        watch:          ['index.html', '_layouts/*.html', '_includes/**/*', '_posts/**/*'],
        watchProd:      'html/**/*.html'
    },
    copy: {
        styles:         'bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/**/*.scss',
        scripts:        'bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/**/*.js'
    },
    clean: {
        img:            'build/img',
        imgProd:        'html/build/img',
        styles:         'build/css',
        stylesProd:     'html/build/css',
        scripts:        'build/js',
        scriptsProd:    'html/build/js',
        build:          'build',
        buildProd:      'html/build',
        prod:           'html'
    }
};



/*==================================
=            Gulp Tasks            =
==================================*/



gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({server: {baseDir: paths.html.dest}});
});

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.styles.watch)
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
        .pipe(sass({outputStyles: 'nested'}))
        .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], {cascade: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.destProd))
        .pipe(size({showFiles: true}))
        .pipe(notify('sass is done.\n'));
});

gulp.task('sass-min', ['sass'], function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.styles.style)
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
        .pipe(cmq({log: true}))
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        // .pipe(zopfli())
        // .pipe(zip('main.css.zip'))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.destProd))
        .pipe(size({showFiles: true}))
        .pipe(notify('Sass-min is done.\n'));
});

gulp.task('sass-reload', ['sass-min'], function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.styles.styleMin)
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('jshint-gulp', function () {
    return gulp.src('gulpfile.js')
        .pipe(cache(jshint('.jshintrc')))
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
        .pipe(notify('jshint-gulp is done.\n'));
});

gulp.task('jshint', ['jshint-gulp'], function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.scripts.script)
        .pipe(cache(jshint('.jshintrc')))
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
        .pipe(notify('jshint-gulp is done.\n'));
});

gulp.task('concat', ['jshint'], function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.bundles.main)
        .pipe(concat('main.bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.dest))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.destProd))
        .pipe(size({showFiles: true}));
});

gulp.task('js', ['concat'], function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.scripts.bundleMain)
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.dest))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.destProd))
        .pipe(notify('js is done.\n'));
});

gulp.task('js-reload', ['js'], function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.scripts.bundleMainMin)
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
        .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});

gulp.task('image-min', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.images.src)
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
        .pipe(cached(imageMin({optimizationLevel: 3, progressive: true, interlaced: true})))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.images.destOpt))
        .pipe(size({showFiles: true}))
        .pipe(notify('image-min is done.\n'));
});

gulp.task('image-resize-sm', ['image-min'], function () {
    return  gulp.src(paths.images.watchOpt)
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
        .pipe(changed(paths.images.dest))
        .pipe(parallel(imageResize({
            width   : 400,
            height  : 300,
            crop    : true,
            upscale : false
        }), os.cpuUsage(function(v) { console.log( 'CPU Usage (%): ' + v ); })))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '-sm'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.images.dest))
        .pipe(size({showFiles: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.images.destProd));
    });

gulp.task('image-resize-md', ['image-resize-sm'], function () {
    return  gulp.src(paths.images.watchOpt)
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
        .pipe(changed(paths.images.dest))
        .pipe(parallel(imageResize({
            width : 800,
            height : 600,
            crop : true,
            upscale : false
        }), os.cpuUsage(function(v) { console.log( 'CPU Usage (%): ' + v ); })))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '-md'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.images.dest))
        .pipe(size({showFiles: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.images.destProd));
});

gulp.task('image-resize-lg', ['image-resize-md'], function () {
    return  gulp.src(paths.images.watchOpt)
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
        .pipe(changed(paths.images.dest))
        .pipe(parallel(imageResize({
            width : 1200,
            height : 900,
            crop : true,
            upscale : false
        }), os.cpuUsage(function(v) { console.log( 'CPU Usage (%): ' + v ); })))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '-lg'}))
        .pipe(size({showFiles: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.images.dest))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.images.destProd));
});

gulp.task('cwebp', ['image-resize-lg'], function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.images.watchProd)
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
        .pipe(changed(paths.images.watchDest))
        .pipe(parallel(cwebp()), os.cpuUsage(function(v) { console.log( 'CPU Usage (%): ' + v ); }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.images.dest))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.images.destProd))
        .pipe(notify('cwebp is done.\n'));
});

gulp.task('img-reload', ['cwebp'], function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.images.destProd)
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
        .pipe(reload({stream:true}))
        .pipe(notify('img-reload is done.\n'));
});

gulp.task('jekyll-build', function (done) {
    browserSync.notify(messages.jekyllBuild);
    return cp.spawn('jekyll', ['build'], {stdio: 'inherit'})
        .on('close', done);
});

gulp.task('jekyll', ['jekyll-build'], function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.html.watchProd)
        .pipe(minifyHTML())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.html.dest));
});

gulp.task('jekyll-rebuild', ['jekyll'], function () {
    reload();
});

gulp.task('copy-css', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.copy.styles)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/scss/vendor'));
});

gulp.task('copy-js', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.copy.scripts)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.destVen));
});

gulp.task('clear-cache', function(done) {
    return cache(cache.caches = {});
});

gulp.task('clean', ['clear-cache'], function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.html.dest, {read: false})
    .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('ngrok', function () {
    ngrok.connect({
        authtoken: 'aGJcNEqh838HDfvyheIe', //2BUMGp1fJDzPal7FvxN2
        //httpauth: 'login:password',
        port: 3000
      }, function(err, url) {
        if (err !== null) {
          console.log( err );
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('pagespeed', ['ngrok'], function () {
    return psi({
        nokey: 'true', // or use key: ‘YOUR_API_KEY’
        url: url,
        strategy: 'mobile'
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', ['sass-min', 'js', 'browser-sync'], function () {
    gulp.watch(paths.styles.watch, ['sass-reload']);
    gulp.watch(paths.scripts.watch, ['js-reload']);
    gulp.watch(paths.images.watch, ['img-reload']);
    gulp.watch(paths.html.watch, ['jekyll-rebuild']);
});
```

In addition to that I also have some questions, but I am mainly concerned on the code quality.

1. How can I properly use [os-utils](https://github.com/oscmejia/os-utils) to output CPU and memory usage in % used over the single task?
2. Does my `onError` function works properly? I'm not quite clear with how to use [beep](https://github.com/mscdex/beepjs) and [gutil](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util).
3. How can I properly cache (or `change`, `remeber`, `cached` or whatever other caching plugin) images for `gulp-resize` and `gulp-cwebp` tasks?

Comment: This `Gulpfile.js` is *monolithic*.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: I was in the middle of writing up a review, but I thought it was a great file and ended up not officially leaving an answer. My only advice would be to separate and restructure the file into a `build/` directory with different tasks, since it is 330+ lines long.

Comment: I probably didn't understand your idea about separating /build directory with different tasks, but I suppose that I don't need any specific tasks for /build directory, because it's always get overwritten by 'jekyll-build' task... Please correct me, if I miss something. Thanks for your review ✌️

Comment: If you'd like, I can leave an answer that provides my advice for the `build/` directory instead of a comment - but it won't have much else.

Comment: Questions 1 and 3 appear off-topic as they're asking about additional implementation.  If you cannot figure out that code elsewhere, then leave them out to keep this on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

My only opinion on your mostly well written Gulpfile is to consider restructuring your [330+ line Gulpfile](https://github.com/Skoks/performer/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L333) into multiple files, separated by grouped tasks.

During an overview of your file, the tasks seemed to be loosely categorized into three groups:

- image modifications
- copying / Jekyll
- JavaScript and Sass

As someone who doesn't like large files of code, I would suggest a `build/` directory and a main `Gulpfile.js` to run your builds. Something along the following tree:

```
/Gulpfile.js
/build/images.js
/build/statics.js
/build/js-sass.js
```

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26532942/2708970) handles the "how to" very nicely. Besides that tip (and some indentation errors), I think the Gulpfile looks great.